# Set file creation time with standard library only

Tags: c++, c++17, portability

C++17 includes a new and portable API for working with filesystems (`<filesystem>`).

My program unpacks an archive. This archive contains files, directories and creatation time for each file. With the new API I have a portable solotution for creating directories (`std::filesystem::create_directories`), and I am using `std::ofstream` for creating files.

Can I use the new API for setting file createtion (or modification) time?

**EDIT**: Time, who providing by archive - it is seconds, start at 1970.01.01 00:00:00(UNIX Epoch time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is... complicated. Because C++ gotta be C++.

In the most technical sense, the answer is yes: `std::filesystem::last_write_time` [can be used to set the last time of writing for the file](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time).

The reason why the answer is not true in a more realistic sense is because `last_write_time` takes a `std::filesystem::file_time_type` as its time. And that's problematic.

See, the epoch for this time point (what constitutes 0 time) is... implementation-defined. It might be UNIX time (Zero is Jan 1, 1970 at 00:00:00). Or it might be something else.

Because it is implementation-defined, there is no way to *portably* turn a count of seconds/minutes/days/etc relative to some known epoch (like, for example, the time in your archive) into a `std::filesystem::file_time_type`, simply because you don't know how to speak `file_time_type`. The only thing you can really do is use existing `file_time_type`s values and adjust them by any arbitrary count of time (or set it to the current time via `file_time_type::clock::now()`). But you can't set a file's time to some known, absolute date/time.

C++20 fortunately plugs this hole. `system_clock` will be required to run on UNIX time, and `file_time_type` will be required to be able to be [`std::chrono::clock_cast`ed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/clock_cast) from/to any type that can be converted to the `system_clock` time.

But until then, `last_write_time` is not nearly as useful as it ought to be...

Comment: How can i get an actual epoch for time point ? (This is maybe  1970.01.01 or other)

Comment: @PavelDev: "*How can i get an actual epoch for time point ?*" You can't (pre-C++20). That's *why* you can't work with `file_time_type` without using implementation-specific code. You would have to look up each implementation's documentation to see how its particular clock code works. The epoch for any time point is always the same: zero. But you'd need to get that epoch relative to some other epoch, and pre-C++20 has no mechanism for that.